# how to set the report virtualizer parameter for jasper reports in java

Tags: java, jasper-reports

How to set the REPORT_VIRTUALIZER parameter for jasper reports i java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://itblackbelt.wordpress.com/2008/02/29/generating-huge-reports-in-jasperreports/) you can find a great article about jasper report virtualization. There are links to sample code in the comments.